# Android ICS-like input field in CSS

Tags: android, html, css

I want to create an input field like Android Ice Cream Sandwich's one in HTML/CSS only and without using images.
I'm stuck with making these small borders (the image below), It would be great if anybody could help.

[image: Android inpu field]

Comment: Sorry, haven't seen your answer.
Tried this:
input[type="text"]{
border:solid cyan 1px;
border-top:solid transparent 1px;
height:5px;
overflow:visible;
}
No way, the overflow is always hidden :(

Comment: can we make this input box through before and after pseudo-elements?

Comment: You might be interested in this similar question with a couple of solutions: http://stackoverflow.com/q/14479606/1254484

Comment: I dont know why this question is closed?

Comment: @vishwanath Neither do I.

Comment: Hmm, just checked history. That happened before the screenshot was added to the question. Seems legit. Can be reopened.

Comment: Question should be reopened. It is a a very legitimate question and  quite a common use case when it comes to HTML5 Mobile App Development.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

**EDIT**

I'd like to include owencm's comment for people stumbling across this question, as i find it quite elegant:

**CSS**

```
input.holo[type='text'] {
    /* You can set width to whatever you like */
    width: 200px;
    font-family: "Roboto", "Droid Sans", sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 8px 8px 6px 8px;
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    outline: none;
    border: none;
    background: bottom left linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, #a9a9a9) no-repeat, bottom center linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, #a9a9a9) repeat-x, bottom right linear-gradient(#a9a9a9, #a9a9a9) no-repeat;
    background-size: 1px 6px, 1px 1px, 1px 6px;
}
input.holo[type='text']:hover, input.holo[type='text']:focus {
    background: bottom left linear-gradient(#0099cc, #0099cc) no-repeat, bottom center linear-gradient(#0099cc, #0099cc) repeat-x, bottom right linear-gradient(#0099cc, #0099cc) no-repeat;
    background-size: 1px 6px, 1px 1px, 1px 6px; 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type='text' class='holo'/>
```

**JSFiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/QKm37/

**Original Solution**

```
<span style="
  border-bottom: solid 1px cyan;
  border-left: solid 1px cyan;
  margin: 20px;
  border-right: solid 1px cyan;
  overflow: visible;
  max-height: 0.2em;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 2px;
">
<input type="text" style="
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  background: transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 0.8em;
">
</span>
```

Comment: i have a maybe better solution .. i will edit your post sorry for that .. but its closed.

Comment: The following works in Chrome without any additional tags: http://jsfiddle.net/QKm37/

Comment: `</input>`… are you kidding me?

Comment: @owencm Can you please explain how the background magic works.